# How to convert bitmaps to 'matrices' that can be processed in C++ ( ANN )?

Tags: c++, image-processing, bitmap

I want to feed my extracted character bitmaps (.bmp files) into some kind of matrices that can be processed in C++ and then fed into the artificial neural network e.g. the network will take 72 inputs - each one as a pixel of the binarized picture of dimensions 6 x 12.

For instance:  I have a binarized bitmap of size let's say 40 x 80. I want to make out of it a structure that will have dimensions 6 x 12 and it would consist of my scaled bitmap. So I need a bitmap library that would allow me to scale the bmps and then fed them into the ANN. (As some of you stated already, they will be stored already as a matrix of so kind so no transformations will be necessary)

What can I use in here ?

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem? To open the file? To read the data? To convert the data into whatever format your ANN library expects? Please be more precise. Note, that if you have more than one problem, you may open more than one question. Do this in order to make the number of actual problems per question as close to 1 as possible.

Comment: @moooeeeep I have updated my question. Please take a look if it's better.

Comment: Take every 6th pixel in X and every 3rd in Y.  Not elegant, but would work as a first pass until you found a better down res-ing solution.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I wanted something like real resize - appropriately resizing my images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that any image processing library could suit your needs. So, my advice would be to use a library that is as simple as possible to integrate in your build process. 
In this context, the CImg library is extremely easy to us, as it is composed of a simple .h file.

Concerning your need, a possible implementation would be

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{
  CImg<unsigned char> image("img/logo.bmp");

  //Simple resize with nearest neighbour interpolation
  //image = image.resize(64, 64); 

  //If you want to specify the interpolation type
  image = image.resize(64, 64, -100, -100, 4);//The last param specifies the interpolation type 
  //\param interpolation_type Method of interpolation :
  //   -1 = no interpolation : raw memory resizing.
  //  - 0 = no interpolation : additional space is filled according to \p border_condition.
  //  - 1 = nearest-neighbor interpolation.
  //  - 2 = moving average interpolation.
  //  - 3 = linear interpolation.
  //  - 4 = grid interpolation.
  //  - 5 = bicubic interpolation.
  //  - 6 = lanczos interpolation.

  CImgDisplay main_disp(image,"Image resized");

  //This last part of code is not usfeul for you, it is only used to display the resized image
  while (!main_disp.is_closed() ) 
    main_disp.wait();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thank a lot for this lib but still I can't get it running. I keep on getting unhandled exception: `+  _message 0x00322ba8 "[instance(0,0,0,0,00000000,non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load_bmp() : Invalid BMP file 'try.bmp'." char [16384]
` and this [image link](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3940/61319346.png)

I put the bmp in the working directory where I put other images for other libraries.

Comment: Ok I fixed it - the problem is with the library - it cannot cooperate with 8 bit bitmaps :/ I hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap file format (see [the specs](http://www.fileformat.info/format/bmp/spec/e27073c25463436f8a64fa789c886d9c/view.htm)) already store bitmaps as a matrix, or more precisely an array of pixels, which can be divided into 2D array by row (or column, but doesn't matter).

Thus you just have to read the header and get the image size, then read the data in arrays of packed `struct` (with no padding, as explained [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)).

This way you will get your matrix, then you can wrap it in a class to store width and height attributes, or even give arrays to constructor of personal-flavor matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Use some sort of bmp lib to access the data (platform dependent).  This will usually give you the bmp as a flat array.  Take that flat array and plug each value into your matrix structure, or pass it directly into your NN code.  Can't offer you much more than this without more info.